# Error installing package GNU radio using PYbombs

Tags: python, c++, configuration, ubuntu-18.04, gnuradio-companion

Hello I am trying to install GNU radio using Pybombs as I need Out Of Tree modules to be added. I tried to install using commands given below

- sudo apt-get install python-pip
- sudo pip install pybombs
- pybombs auto-config
- pybombs recipes add-defaults
- pybombs prefix init ~/gnuradio -R gnuradio-default
  (wait a while)
- . ~/gnuradio/setup_env.sh

but the installation ends up with following error

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

- PyBOMBS.Packager.source - ERROR - Configuration failed after running at least twice.
- PyBOMBS.Packager.source - ERROR - Problem occurred while building package gnuradio:
  Configuration failed
- PyBOMBS.install_manager - ERROR - Error installing package gnuradio. Aborting.

I tried to install on Ubuntu version 18.04(bionic) and now on ununtu 16.04(xenial) but ended up with the same error. Can anyone help me. Is there any specific requirement of configuration of laptop regarding processor and memory?

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot that could have happened, which unfortunately isn't seen from your question. Normally, when PyBOMBS fails, it runs again the culprit command with higher verbosity, which will then allow you to check what happened in more detail. E.g:

```
$ pybombs -v prefix init ~/gnuradio -R gnuradio-default
```

The verbosity can be stacked (i.e `-vv` or `-vvv` for higher verbosity levels).

My suggestion: run again the  PyBOMBS install command, with the verbosity option, and if the output is still unclear for what you need to do to fix it, then use some pastebin online service to send us a link with the whole output. Without these details it is, unfortunately, hard to give you a hand.

FYI: I've installed GNURadio with PyBOMBS in both those OS versions and haven't had any major problems before. Normally processor and memory configurations aren't directly regarded during installation.